# Regex extract phrases with all caps ending with colon

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that will return a collection of phrases that are all caps ending in a colon. Example:

MEDICATIONS ON ADMISSION :Vasotec 40 mg q.day , Soma 1 tablet q.day , Demerolprn , Clonidine . ALLERGIES :The patient has no known drug allergies .PAST MEDICAL HISTORY :As described above .
FAMILY HISTORY :The family history is positive for diabetes mellitus , positive for cancer .

I need to extract the following:

MEDICATIONS ON ADMISSION, ALLERGIES, FAMILY HISTORY

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to work: `[A-Z ]+ :`

`[A-Z]` gets any character that is a letter or a space; the plus sign searches for groups of one of more of them. The colon isn't a special character and doesn't need to be escaped.

Make sure your search is case sensitive if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you might want to try this:

```
/([A-Z]*\s+?)+:/um
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text is a single block consisting of multiple paragraphs, you will have to enable an option to treat newlines as normal characters. This is dependent on your regex library and language of choice.

If you want to extract multiple phrases from a single block like this, you will also have to enclose your basic pattern within a repeating group, with appropriate wildcards ("[^A-Z ]*") to ignore succeeding non-phrase text. Again, how to do this depends on your choice of library and language.

If you are processing each line separately and collecting the phrases, this isn't necessary.